# Rails activerecord get user with id dividable by 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to get user who has an ID dividable by 3

something like :

```
User.where(id: id % 3 == 0)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure string condition here, because data is static (not coming from user for example):

```
User.where('id % 3 = 0')
```

Read more in [official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions).

Comment: Note that other database systems may require something other than "%" (see the Oracle example in another answer).

Comment: @MichaelChaney Good remark, user didn't mention used database system.

Answer (score 2):

If the database is Oracle, then you can do the following:

```
User.where('mod(id, 3) = 0')
```

Query:

```
2.1.2-perf :004 > User.where('mod(id, 3) = 0').to_sql
 => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (mod(id, 3) = 0)"
```

Sql fiddle demo for this query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/066679/3).

Comment: Good answer for users of other databases :)